# How to run VBA macro in win32 when used as a variable

Tags: python, vba, winapi

I am writing a script which opens an excel sheet and enters some data and runs a VBA macro.

```
import os
import win32com.client
import glob

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
working_dir = os.getcwd()

path = os.path.join(working_dir, 'folder')
file_list = glob.glob(path + '/*.xls*')
for file in file_list:
    file_name = str(file)
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
    wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate()
    ws = wb.Activesheet.Name
    ws1 = wb.Worksheets(ws)
    ws1.Range("E5").FormulaR1C1 = "add_text_here"
    xl.Goto(ws1.Range('E5'))
    xl.Run("excel_sheet.xls!macro")
    wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
    xl.Quit()
```

I am able to run this script properly. The problem I get is, when I change the run macro to read from a variable like below.

```
xl.Run(file_name+"!macro") # here I changed file name to a variable
```

I get

> The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

error.

I really need to do this because I dont want to give the Excel file name hard coded and this Excel file may change. Please help me.

Comment: Since you use `file_name` to open the file `xl.Workbooks.Open(file_name)` it looks like this must contain the entire path including the file name and not only the file name as in `xl.Run("excel_sheet.xls!macro")` check the value of `file_name` if it conains a path rename your variable so it is clear it does not contain a file name but a path and a file name. Misleading variable names are very often the cause of errors. • Then make sure you use the file name only for `xl.Run` (without path).

Comment: The easy way is to use `xl.Run(wb.Name+"!macro")`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, You are right file name contains the path. I did not know that xl.run should only contain file name without path. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: @АлексейР Thank you this solved my problem. Thank you both of you for helping me out. I really was stuck at this line.

Comment: @АлексейР Looks like that's the perfect solution. Why don't you post it as an anwser?

Comment: @Peh Your solution is also correct, but you also did not post in the solution. Posted.

Comment: @АлексейР yes because mine was not a real solution but more a hint. But yours perfectly solves the entire question. That's why I suggested to post your's as answer not mine.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to use

```
xl.Run(wb.Name+"!macro")
```